# Are we going to get the beta badge for participating in the private beta of Gaming?

Tags: discussion, badges

Do we get the beta badge or is that for Stack Overflow alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will get it, although it is only awarded to private beta users.

The badge is awarded shortly after the public beta starts

Comment: I think it'll be awarded once the beta ends, and like the SO version only if you satisfied some requirement of activity.

Comment: One of the criteria is that you need to get a certain number of badges - I think it's 5 which is why I didn't get it on Server Fault.

Comment: We should have a gold private beta badge and silver public beta badge.

Comment: Where do we need to go to get the activity requirements?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember reading somewhere on MetaSO that they are going to give a "Founder" badge for users who committed to the site on Area 51 and participated in the beta, and a "Beta" badge to anyone who participated in the public beta. But I can't find a reference...

Comment: @Kip http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges "Participated in the definition, commitment, and beta phases of a successful site"

Comment: Aside from the badge description itself, [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/webapps-beta-badge) indicates that it actually only applies to those who participated in the private beta.

Comment: @ChrisF: it's three, not five. [Quoting Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/105#105): "You must generate 3 bronze badges PRIOR to the beta becoming public to be eligible. This is quite trivial to do."

Comment: @Reg - It was a while ago when Server Fault came out of beta, so I'm not surprised I got it wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I received the beta badge as soon as Area51 confirmed my commitment was fulfilled. I'm afraid an Area51 commitment is currently required for the badge :(